# logr is working but causing error messages

Tags: logging

I would like to log some outputs and any error/warning/messages produced by R when executing a script. I found the logr package suitable. But when I tried the example in its documentation, it is producing error messages even though it seems to be mostly working (i.e. logging the desired contents) except that lf was not found in the last line of code. Could someone help me out please?

On RStudio console:
[image]

Log:
[image]

Comment: Tse: What version of R and R Studio are you using?  I use logr a lot, and have never seen this error.

Comment: I see some other people got the locked binding error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725106/r-how-to-clear-all-warnings

Comment: Also the version of logr.

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for taking a look at my question. The errors resolved after I upgraded to R 4.0.3 and RStudio 1.3.1093. Nonetheless, FYI, the errors happened when I was using R 3.6.1, RStudio 1.1.463 and logr 1.1.1.

Comment: Good to know!  Thanks!