# How to clear all warnings as of R 4.1.0

Tags: r

As of R 4.1.0 you cannot clear all previous warnings using `assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())`

Putting any considerations aside of whether it is a good idea to clear all warnings; how can you do this in R 4.1.0?

There is a very old thread which references the issue pre and post 4.1.0. But I didn't come away with a clear answer post 4.1.0

Comment: [Martin Mächler's recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497026/8245406) to your very old thread seems to do what you want.

Comment: It still seems to work with R 4.1.0 *provided* a warning has been encountered in the session.

Comment: Since it works iff there are errors my solution has been to wrap a tryCatch around the original code. I couldn't work out how to use Martin's code to do exactly what I wanted: ie to remove all current warnings. The background is that I am using read_excel to read in data and need to know which columns it is not guessing the class for.